# using kmeans within an apply function in r

Tags: r, list, apply, k-means

i am facing a new challenge today! I would like to perform a kmeans on each line of my table separately (in my case this represents monthly weather data)   get a table for each point and month with cluster number.

### The illustration

#### here is an extract of the data (i have about 1700 observations in total showing only 10 here)

```
data<-c( 
 245,      84 ,     99 ,  161,   249, 190 , 136 , 122 ,   157,       128  ,   123 ,     138 ,     106,
 246,      84 ,    101,   163 ,  257, 194 , 138 , 126 ,   163,       134  ,   127 ,     142 ,     108,
 247,     60  ,    80  , 131,   191, 156 ,  90  , 82  ,  106 ,       85  ,    86 ,     106  ,     88,
 248,      60 ,     80  , 131 ,  191, 156,   90 ,  82,    106 ,       85 ,     86 ,     106  ,     88,
 249 ,     60 ,     80 ,  131,   191, 156,   90,   82,    106 ,       85 ,     86 ,     106  ,     88,
 250 ,     58 ,     79 ,  131,   197, 156,   90,   78,    101 ,       84 ,     84 ,     106  ,     88,
 251 ,     60 ,     81 ,  135,   210, 163,   91,   82,    107 ,       88 ,     89 ,     108  ,     89,
 252 ,     67 ,     86 ,  140,   214, 168,  105,   92,    121 ,       99 ,     99 ,     114 ,      93,
 253,      70 ,     89 ,  144,   225, 171 , 110,   97,    128 ,      105 ,    104 ,     118 ,      94,
 254,      70 ,     89 ,  144,   225, 171,  110,   97,    128 ,      105 ,    104 ,     118 ,      94,
 255,      62 ,     82,   134,   205, 163 ,  94,   85,    110 ,       88 ,     90,      109,       89)
data<-matrix(data, nrow=10,ncol=13,byrow=FALSE) 
data<-data.frame(data)
names(data)<-c('ID' ,'January' ,'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May' ,'June' ,'July' ,'August' ,'September' ,'October', 'November', 'December')
```

#### performing a kmeans classification on each observation line

as you see i work with 2 clusters

```
kmean<-apply(data[,2:13], 1,  function(x) {kmeans(x, 2)})
```

Great this works, and creates a list with the kmeans reports (that are also list,of which the second one is the cluster number)

i can look at the cluster numbers for a specific line, say line 2 like this

```
kmean[[2]]$cluster
```

#### the challenge

now i would like to get a table that gives me the result of kmean$cluster for each observation in my dataframe.

So i tried the following :

```
cluster<-apply(kmean, 1, function (y) {kmean[[y]]$cluster})
```

But then i get the following error : 
*Error in apply(kmean, 1, function(y) { : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length*

Any suggestion how i can get my table showing for each line and each month to which cluster the observation belongs to?

A great thanks for looking at this! Catherine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(kmean), function(x) kmean[[x]]$cluster))
```